# i am trying to make a set of numbers into letters but when i run the program there is no output

Tags: java

I am trying to make a set of numbers into letters but when I run the program there is no output

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class program
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a set of numbers between 1 and 26 separated by a comma: ");
        String s = S.nextLine();
        String[] number = s.split("[\\S,]+");
        for (int a = 0; a < number.length; a++)
        {
            if (number[a].equals("1"))
            {
                number[a] = number[a].replace(number[a], "A");
            }
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < number.length; a++)
        {
            if (number[a].equals("2"))
            {
                number[a] = number[a].replace(number[a], "B");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to print something for there to be output.

Comment: Seems like your loop will goes out of bound for number.length

Comment: @Sky Because it is a < and not a <= the loop correctly iterates through itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you change:

```
String[] number = s.split("[\\S,]+");
```

To:

```
String[] number = s.split(",+");
```

I think it should work fine.

Also I would recommend using nested for loops to find a, b, ect. But that is just my opinion.

You could also convert from numbers to letters using ASCII (by casting an int to a char).

And of course you need to print the results, however I assume that is in your entire block code.